# Shopify app development CLI 3 - Vite error when importing Shopify-api : "optimized info should be defined"

Tags: shopify, vite, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I'm trying to import Shopiy-api so I can make requests using it but it returns an error -

> ┃ Vite Error, /node_modules/.vite/deps/@shopify_shopify-api.js?t=... optimized info should be defined

any help?